# Can I build an xpath expression via linq?

Tags: linq, xpath

I'm working with an existing C# API that accepts string XPath expressions (ActiveMQ message body constraints, but that's not an important detail).

I'm a newcomer to Linq. Is it possible to build up a Linq predicate and export that as an XPath expression?

I'm interested because of Linq's strong typing and syntax checking compared with a simple XPath string.

Comment: Your question isn't all that clear, but are you looking for [Get the XPath to an XElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451950/get-the-xpath-to-an-xelement)

Comment: @Ani - yes, I think that's very close to what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use Linq to Xml provider, you can found an example here:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/06/05/from-linq-to-xpath-and-back-again.aspx

Comment: Huh? That link's page doesn't have the word "provider" anywhere on it. Did you paste the wrong link?

Comment: Hi the link is correct, Linq to Xml provider is a built in linq provider available with .net framework.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you were saying *write* a provider.