# Using Linq To XML, method to get path to all leaves?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, tree, linq-to-xml

Ok, I've got the following XML tree

```xml
<root>
    <A>
        <A1>
            <A1A>1000</A1A>
            <A1B>2000</A1B>
            <A1C>3000</A1C>
        </A1>
        <A2>
            <A2A>4000</A2A>
            <A2B>5000</A2B>
        </A2>
    </A>
    <B>
        <B1>
            <B1A>6000</B1A>
        </B1>
    </B>
</root>
```

From a method receiving an XDocument I want to produce a dictionary where the key is the path (really an XPath) and the value comes from the value in the corresponding leaf.

```
root/A/A1/A1A    1000
root/A/A1/A1B    2000
root/A/A1/A1C    3000
root/A/A2/A2A    4000
root/A/A2/A2B    5000
root/B/B1/B1A    6000
```

Seems simple to do in Linq to XML but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the leaves by looking for elements that have no descendants:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var leaves = 
    from e in doc.Descendants()
    where !e.Elements().Any()
    select e;
```

I don't know if there is a built-in way to get the path of an element, but you can easily create an extension method to build it:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static string Path(this XElement element)
    {
        XElement tmp = element;
        string path = string.Empty;
        while (tmp != null)
        {
            path = "/" + tmp.Name + path;
            tmp = tmp.Parent;
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

You can then build the dictionary like this:

```
var dict = leaves.ToDictionary(e => e.Path(), e => e.Value);
```

Comment: Careful with the indexes of elements, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451950/get-the-xpath-to-an-xelement

Comment: I was so deep in finding a way to do this in LinqToXml that I completely overlooked how simple it is to just build the path using the parents... doh! I will leave the question open for a little while in case someone knows of a way to do it in LinqToXml. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

After parsing the XML to an XDocument, which I assume you've already been able to do, use the methods below.  Note that the `GetPath()` implementation is fairly naiive.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/454597/115650) for a better implementation.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetLeaves(XDocument doc)
{
    var dict = doc
        .Descendants()
        .Where(e => !e.HasElements)
        .ToDictionary(e => GetPath(e), e.Value);

    return dict;
}

private string GetPath(XElement element)
{
    var nodes = new List<string>();
    var node = element;
    while (node != null)
    {
        nodes.Add(node.Name.ToString());
        node = node.Parent;
    }

    return string.Join("/", Enumerable.Reverse(nodes));
}
```

Comment: I don't see the need to use an extension like the other answer did. To me, this answer looks more elegant, readable and maintainable.

Comment: I like the use of `HasElements`.  For GetPath, did you consider recursion - `return (element.Parent == null ? "" : GetPath(element.Parent)) + "/" + element.Name.ToString());`

Comment: Or use a `Stack<String>` instead of a `List<String>`... then use `Push` instead of `Add` and don't have to use the `Enumerable.Reverse`