# Determine if JToken is leaf

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to dynamically find the names of leaf nodes of a JSON object whose structure isn't known in advance. First, I'm parsing the string into a list of JTokens, like this:

```
        string req = @"{'creationRequestId':'A',
                        'value':{
                            'amount':1.0,
                            'currencyCode':'USD'
                        }
                        }";
        var tokens = JToken.Parse(req);
```

Then I'd like to identify which are leaves. In the above example, `'creationRequestId':'A'`, `'amount':1.0`, and `'currencyCode':'USD'` are the leaves, and the names are `creationRequestId`, `amount`, and `currencyCode`.

### Attempt that works, but is slightly ugly

The below example recursively traverses the JSON tree and prints the leaf names:

```
    public static void PrintLeafNames(IEnumerable<JToken> tokens)
    {
        foreach (var token in tokens)
        {
            bool isLeaf = token.Children().Count() == 1 && !token.Children().First().Children().Any();
            if (token.Type == JTokenType.Property && isLeaf)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(((JProperty)token).Name);
            }

            if (token.Children().Any())
                PrintLeafNames(token.Children<JToken>());
        }
    }
```

This works, printing:

```
creationRequestId
amount
currencyCode
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a less ugly expression for determining whether a JToken is a leaf:

```
bool isLeaf = token.Children().Count() == 1 && !token.Children().First().Children().Any();
```

[Incidentally, this is a one-liner in XML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795479/using-linq-to-xml-method-to-get-path-to-all-leaves)

Comment: Why doesn't `!token.Children().Any()` suffice?

Comment: That's precisely what `HasValues` is for.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot and @JeffMercado : I've tried both of those since they seemed like the obvious solution, and neither works. The reason is that (for example) on the JToken `'creationRequestId':'A'`, the expression `!token.Children().Any()` evaluates to `false`. If you run the code, you'll see what I mean: nothing gets printed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you've defined a leaf as any `JProperty` whose value does not have any child values.  You can use the `HasValues` property on the `JToken` to help make this determination:

```
public static void PrintLeafNames(IEnumerable<JToken> tokens)
{
    foreach (var token in tokens)
    {
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Property)
        {
            JProperty prop = (JProperty)token;
            if (!prop.Value.HasValues)
                Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
        }
        if (token.HasValues)
            PrintLeafNames(token.Children());
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/e216YS

Comment: This fails in case when value is empty object e.g. 'value': {}

Comment: @ApurvGupta An empty object does not have any child values; therefore, `value` is a leaf according to the definition in the question.  It sounds like you might have a different definition of a leaf, where you require the property value to be a primitive (as opposed to an empty object or empty array).  If that is the case, you can make it work the way you want by changing the conditional `if (!prop.Value.HasValues)` to `if (prop.Value is JValue)`.