# .NET convert three tag into list

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dictionary

I would like to convert a text which contains tag three into a list. Example :

```
var raw = @"<root><group><tag1>text1</tag1><tag3>text3</tag3</group><tag2>text2</tag2></root>";
```

And I need to have something like this :

```
Dictionary<string,string> dicTags = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dicTags["tag1"] = "text1";
dicTags["tag3"] = "text3";
dicTags["tag2"] = "text2";
```

Here is a example (working but not with this multiple three). The added tag `<group></group>` make it fail :

```
var raw = @"<root><group><tag1>text1</tag1><tag3>text3</tag3></group><tag2>text2</tag2></root>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(raw);
var result = doc.Root.Elements().ToDictionary(e => (string)e.Name.LocalName, e => (string)e);
foreach(var kv in result){
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
}
```

Comment: The other question is answered. This is quite similar but this actually an other question. Because the <group></group> tag make it fail :/

Comment: What's your criteria for what gets added to the dictionary?  Only elements with no child elements?  Anything that starts with `tag`?

Comment: Anything that has a direct value. <group></group> doesn't have one but <tag1>text1</tag1> has the value text1 on it. So it has to have no child and a value in it.

Comment: In any case, do some research on how to modify your Linq-to-XML query to get the elements you need.  Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8795591/1081897) will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comments I came up with this:

```
var raw = 
     @"<root><group><tag1>text1</tag1><tag3>text3</tag3></group><tag2>text2</tag2></root>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(raw);
var result = doc.Descendants()
            .Where(el => !el.HasElements)
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v.Value);
```

If you want to ignore tags like `<tag4><tag4>` (no descendants and empty value) then change the condition to the following:

```
.Where(el => !el.HasElements && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `XMLDocument` load your string with LoadXML() method than read your XMLstring.

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xmlstring);

foreach(XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes){
   string text = node.InnerText; 
}
```