# Getting XPath for node with XmlReader

Tags: c#, xmlreader, xmlnode

How to get XPath for the current node with `XMLReader`?

E.g.:

```xml
<Employee>
    <Entity>
        <Id>1</Id>
    </Entity>
</Employee>
```

So I need to get XPath for `1` which is `Employee/Entity/Id`. Any ideas?

```csharp
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(basePath, settings))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {                   
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            // need to get xpath of the text node
        }
        else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            // need to get xpath of the current node
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You'd have to keep track of what elements you're inside - you could use a stack and push each element as it's read and pop it when you reach EndElement.  What are you trying to do, though?  Do you need to drop down to `XmlReader`?  This would be easier using a DOM like `XDocument`.

Comment: @CharlesMager, Can you please provide some example ?

Comment: XmlReader can't use XPath.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I need to iterate all nodes in a `Xml` and need to get `XPath` of each node? Is that can be done using `XDocument`? If so, Can you post some example ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to use a higher level API like LINQ to XML.  The only reason to use a low level API like `XmlReader` is for extremely large files.  With LINQ to XML, a naive implementation is fairly trivial:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach (var element in doc.Descendants())
{
    var path = element.AncestorsAndSelf().Select(e => e.Name.LocalName).Reverse();
    var xPath = string.Join("/", path);
}
```

Using `XmlReader` is a bit more involved as you have to track the element path as you go:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(basePath, settings))
{
    var elements = new Stack<string>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                if(!reader.IsEmptyElement)
                    elements.Push(reader.LocalName);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                elements.Pop();
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                path = string.Join("/", elements.Reverse());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dpOzuL

Note that while this works for your trivial example, this is a very naive creation of an `XPath` expression and won't work in all cases (for example, when you have multiple siblings with the same name or when namespaces are involved).

Comment: Thanks for your time, Is it possible to iterate all elements in a xml using xdocument and then take xpath? The code you posted will work only on the schema as per in the question

Comment: @SSS I've updated to iterate all elements.  It's unclear what you're using this for.  If you want a less naive implementation that would get you a valid XPath in all situations, then look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451950/get-the-xpath-to-an-xelement).