# json foreach loop (without json.net)

Tags: c#, json, foreach

I'm currently trying to create a small launcher to solve some problems using the existing launcher from minecraft.
I'm trying to read a .json file to get all the informations that i need.
If you need to take a look at the .json file [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.10.2/1.10.2.json).

I got it working if i just need a single information like

```
string clienturl = readJson("//downloads/client/url");
```

with this:

```
private string readJson(string element)
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(appPath + "1.10.2.json"));
    var jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json), new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());

    var root = XElement.Load(jsonReader);

    return root.XPathSelectElement(element).Value;
}
```

The problem now is that i need to get informations for all the other files.
The "element" would be:

```
libraries/downloads/artifact/path
libraries/downloads/artifact/url
```

but obviously there is more then one entry for "path" and "url" so i need a foreach loop.
What do i need to change in my code above to make it working with a foreach loop?

Sorry for my bad english, i hope its not to hard to understand.

Small preview of the .json in case you dont want to download the file:

```
"libraries": [
{
    "name": "com.mojang:netty:1.6",
    "downloads": {
        "artifact": {
            "size": 7877,
            "sha1": "4b75825a06139752bd800d9e29c5fd55b8b1b1e4",
            "path": "com/mojang/netty/1.6/netty-1.6.jar",
            "url": "https://libraries.minecraft.net/com/mojang/netty/1.6/netty-1.6.jar"
        }
    }
},
{
    "name": "oshi-project:oshi-core:1.1",
    "downloads": {
        "artifact": {
            "size": 30973,
            "sha1": "9ddf7b048a8d701be231c0f4f95fd986198fd2d8",
            "path": "oshi-project/oshi-core/1.1/oshi-core-1.1.jar",
            "url": "https://libraries.minecraft.net/oshi-project/oshi-core/1.1/oshi-core-1.1.jar"
        }
    }
},
{
    "name": "net.java.dev.jna:jna:3.4.0",
    "downloads": {
        "artifact": {
            "size": 1008730,
            "sha1": "803ff252fedbd395baffd43b37341dc4a150a554",
            "path": "net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar",
            "url": "https://libraries.minecraft.net/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar"
        }
    }
}
]
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use a json library? You will be finished in 2 minutes using them

Comment: @SirRufo there are many ways to work with .json files in .net, the one i'm using above is only one. I just dont realy see a "need" to use third party libraries to get what i want. i'm sure there are also many ways to loop through .json without third party libraries, i'm currently just dont know how.

Comment: Sure there are a lot of ways and you can build a house with a kids shovel. I recommend to use the right tools for the job to get the work done. With Json.NET you will be finished in 2 minutes. Just my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your JSON contains an array, and it's not immediately obvious how `JsonReaderWriterFactory` maps an array to XML elements, given that XML doesn't have the concept of an array.

One way to determine this is to read through the documentation [Mapping Between JSON and XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924435.aspx) which describes this mapping.  But another is simply to determine for ourselves, by using one of the answers from [Get the XPath to an XElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451950/get-the-xpath-to-an-xelement) to find out the actual paths for each element.  Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451950/get-the-xpath-to-an-xelement/23541182#23541182), the following code:

```
var paths = root.DescendantsAndSelf().Select(e => e.GetAbsoluteXPath()).ToList();
Debug.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", paths));
```

Produces output like:

```
/root/libraries
/root/libraries/item[1]
/root/libraries/item[1]/name
/root/libraries/item[1]/downloads
/root/libraries/item[1]/downloads/artifact
/root/libraries/item[1]/downloads/artifact/size
/root/libraries/item[1]/downloads/artifact/sha1
/root/libraries/item[1]/downloads/artifact/path
/root/libraries/item[1]/downloads/artifact/url
/root/libraries/item[2]
/root/libraries/item[2]/name
/root/libraries/item[2]/downloads
/root/libraries/item[2]/downloads/artifact
/root/libraries/item[2]/downloads/artifact/size
/root/libraries/item[2]/downloads/artifact/sha1
/root/libraries/item[2]/downloads/artifact/path
/root/libraries/item[2]/downloads/artifact/url
```

So, as you can see, each array item is placed in a synthetic `<item>` node.

Thus you can query your paths and urls as follows:

```
var files = root
    .XPathSelectElements("libraries/item/downloads/artifact")
    .Select(e => new PathAndUrl { Path = (string)e.Element("path"), Url = (string)e.Element("url") })
    .ToList();
```

Placing the result into a list of the following class:

```
public class PathAndUrl
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```