# Finding the node position on an XDocument

Tags: xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, maui

I'm working on a XIB to XAML (Xam.Forms and .NET MAUI) converter. I've generated a lit of the connections from the XIB but have hit a snag on constructing the XAML.

My old approach was to take each connection, grab the fragment based on the connection and throw it into an `AbsoluteLayout`. This sort of works, but it makes the XAML a bit of a mess and if you have the likes of a `UIScrollView` inside of the View itself, really messes things up (the elements inside the `UIscrollview` need to be held within the XAML `ScrollView`)

To ensure the XAML is being correctly generated, I'm trying to implement an indexing system so the likes of a `UITabBar` and `UIScorllView` have the correct elements within them.

My issue is that for these container types, I have an Id from the connector, but can't find the index of the node.

I have the following in my code

```
// I've read the xib in and obtained the connections
// I then iterate through the connections to get the property and destination
// which is stored in a dictionary<string, string>
// now to find the id from the dictionary.Value

var d = XDocument.Load(infile);
var nod = d.Descendants();
foreach (var t in Outlets.Values) 
{
    var c = 0;
    if (d.Root.Attribute("id").Value == t)
    {
        // I have the correct id for the connection
        // how do I get the index for this subview 
        // or am I better off storing the subview fragment
        // parsing that, then the next etc.
    }
}
```

The `id` attribute matches the destination so the if check works, however, I can't find the index of the line in the XIB so can't parse the objects in that subview

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you mean by the "index of the node", but you can generate an XPath to a specific element using [Get the XPath to an XElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/451950).  Then, given an XPath, use [`XPathSelectElements`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/query-linq-xml-xpath) to get the element.  Does that answer your question?