# How do I select the shallowest matching elements with XPath?

Tags: .net, xpath, xpath-1.0

Let's say I have this document.

```
<a:Root>
    <a:A>
        <title><a:B/></title>
        <a:C>
            <item><a:D/></item>
        </a:C>
    </a:A>
</a:Root>
```

And I have an XmlNode set to the `<a:A>` element.

If I say

```
A.SelectNodes( "//a:*", namespaceManager )
```

I get `B`, `C`, and `D`.  But I don't want `D` because it's nested in another "a:" element.

If I say

```
A.SelectNodes( "//a:*[not(ancestor::a:*)]", namespaceManager )
```

of course, I get nothing, since both A and its parent are in the "a" namespace.

How can I select just `B` and `C`, that is, the shallowest children matching the namespace?

Thanks.

Note, this is XPath 1.0 (.NET 2), so I can't use in-scope-prefixes (which it appears would help).

Also, this isn't really a question about namespaces.  The quandary would be the same with other matching criteria.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for the only pure XPath 1.0 solution so far. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't doable with a single XPath 1.0 expression. Extending on Marc's answer which uses XSLT, you can do this for 1.0:

```
<xsl:variable name="n" select="count(ancestor-or-self::a:*)" />
<xsl:variable name="result" select=".//a:*[count(ancestor::a:*) = $n]" />
```

or the equivalent sequence of C# calls for `Select...`.

Comment: Thanks, I phrased it slightly differently (and of course in C#), but the technique of comparing the counts was clever.

Comment: This is *not* an XSLT question.

Comment: @Dimitre: that much is clear, but the corresponding C# code is trivial to write.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
<xsl:variable name="parents" select="ancestor-or-self::a:*" />
<xsl:value-of select="//a:*[not(deep-equal(ancestor::a:*, $parent))]" />
```

In XSLT this seems simple to do (store a node set as a variable), but I don't exactly know how to implement this in C#.

*Edit:* Working further on the idea of using count, this can probably work:

```
int nrParents = A.SelectNodes("ancestor-or-self::a:*", namespaceManager).Count(); // Or was it Size?
A.SelectNodes("//a:*[count(ancestor::a:*)!=" + nrParents + "]", namespaceManager)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not using XSLT here, or XPath 2.0.  Indeed, .NET still does not support XPath 2.0.

Comment: `deep-equal` is XPath/XSLT 2.0

Comment: @Pavel, I beg to differ.  But in any case, I tried using deep-equal and .NET does not recognize it.

Comment: @harpo: it was a comment to Marc's reply, not to your comment (I didn't see it when I posted). It actually says the same thing that yours does :)

Comment: This is not an XSLT question.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an XSLT question, so here is a single XPath expression that selects the two nodes wanted**:

```
/*/*/descendant::a:*[not(count(ancestor::a:*) > 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I went with something very much like this.  But because the depth of the starting node was unknown, I did have to calculate it in a separate step.

Comment: @harpo: In your case, was the starting node known, eg. did you have an XPath expression selecting the starting node?

Comment: No, I just had an XmlNode reference.  Actually, I ended up building path expressions for the selected nodes using a routine adapted from Jon Skeet's answer to another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241238/how-to-get-xpath-from-an-xmlnode-instance-c/241291#241291