# Can we get the XPATH of an NODE

Tags: vbscript

Hi is there a anyway to get the xpath exression of all the node in an xml or getting xpath of an xml node.is there any property in XMLDOM object ?

Comment: please explain more as to what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it is not standard functionality of the XMLDOM object. Get the way of working from [this C# snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/241291/598599) and transpose it to VBScript.

Comment: Dont you think this should be an comment and not answer?

Comment: @AshReva I've learned to put the same amount of work in an answer as in the question. So I think this answer is appropriate for now. I'll find the `edit` button as soon the OP can deliberate more, show us some attempts and put some actual work in it.

Comment: Ok agree sir very much