# Return XPath for each XML text element

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I want to return a XPath or similar for each text element in the following XML. 
I tried `XPathNodeIterator`, but it seems return nodes under specified node level only. How can I get all nodes and sub-nodes and return a list of objects like below?

```
String exp = "/*/*/child::*";
XPathNodeIterator NodeIter = navigator.Select(exp);
```

XML:

```
<div>
    <p>Title</p>
    <ul>
       <li>Features</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li>Name</li>
       <li>Age</li>
       <li>Gender</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <p>Bill</p>
    <p>Link</p>
</div>
```

Desired Results:
I want to get a list of something like `(div/p[1], Title), (div/ul[1]/li[1], Features), (div/ul[2]/li[1], Name), (div/ul[2]/li[2], Age), (div/ul[2]/li[3], Gender), (div/h2[1], Comments), (div/p[2], Bill), (div/p[3], Link)`

Comment: Since then is `[0]` XPath? The index starts at `1` with XPath. If you want to select elements not containing other elements then `//*[not(*)]` should do. As for generating XPath expressions, what do you want to do with XML and namespaces?

Comment: You want `ui` instead of `ul`?

Comment: I suggest you give recursion a try, come back and we'll help you if you have problems with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are you trying to 1) Find all `XmlElement` nodes that have a text value?  Traverse an `XmlElement` hierarchy and generate an XPath query for each one that uniquely specifies it?

Comment: @Chuck Savage it was a typo and should be ul.

Comment: @AlexW. If I understood the question, I have posted an answer that I believe will get the result you need.

Comment: Alex W.: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4747858/36305

Comment: It's for Linq-to-XML not the older `XmlNode` API, but still related: [Get the XPath to an XElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451950/get-the-xpath-to-an-xelement).

Comment: Even more closely related: [How to get xpath from an XmlNode instance. C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241238/how-to-get-xpath-from-an-xmlnode-instance-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find a built-in method that would give you the kind of path that you wanted. But I was able to create a recursive function that would do the trick. Here is the code I came up with:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string xmlText = textBox1.Text;

        String exp = "//text()";
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(xmlText);

        //Writes the text out to a textbox
        foreach (XmlNode x in xml.SelectNodes(exp))
            textBox2.AppendText("(" + GetPath(x) + ", " + x.InnerText + ")\n");
    }

    string GetPath(XmlNode nd)
    {
        if (nd.ParentNode != null && nd.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            return GetPath(nd.ParentNode);
        }
        else if (nd.ParentNode != null && nd.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            var index = nd.ParentNode.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().ToList().IndexOf(nd);
            string path = GetPath(nd.ParentNode);
            path += (path != "") ? "/" : "";
            return string.Format("{0}{1}[{2}]", path, nd.Name, index);
        }
        else return "";
    }
```

I was testing it on a `Form`, thus the button click event. Using `//text()` to get all text nodes was the easy part. Coming up with a recursive function to build the path was a little harder than I expected. It took me a bit to figure out that by casting `ParentNode.ChildNodes` to a collection of `XmlNode`, then converting to a list, we can use the `IndexOf()` method of `List` to get the index.

Results:

```
(div[0]/p[0], Title)
(div[0]/ul[1]/li[0], Features)
(div[0]/ul[2]/li[0], Name)
(div[0]/ul[2]/li[1], Age)
(div[0]/ul[2]/li[2], Gender)
(div[0]/h2[3], Comments)
(div[0]/p[4], Bill)
(div[0]/p[5], Link)
```

One caveat to this that I see, and because I don't know what application you will be using this for, but if you are going to be using this to get elements from HTML, the `LoadXML()` function may break. "Valid" HTML is not necessarily valid XML, and the load may fail.

Comment: Thanks jwatts1980. Your codes worked. I am modifying your solution to see if it can be done using XDocument.

Answer (score 1):

**Just run this transformation in .NET** (using XslCompiledTransform):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vApos">'</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::*" mode="path"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('=',$vApos,.,$vApos)"/>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="path">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name())"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vnumPrecSiblings" select=
      "count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])"/>
    <xsl:if test="$vnumPrecSiblings or following-sibling::*[name()=name(current())]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', $vnumPrecSiblings +1, ']')"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided source XML document**:

```
<div>
    <p>Title</p>
    <ul>
       <li>Features</li>
    </ul>
    <p/>
    <ul>
       <li>Name</li>
       <li>Age</li>
       <li>Gender</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <p>Bill</p>
    <p>Link</p>
</div>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
/div/p[1]='Title'
/div/ul[1]/li='Features'
/div/ul[2]/li[1]='Name'
/div/ul[2]/li[2]='Age'
/div/ul[2]/li[3]='Gender'
/div/h2='Comments'
/div/p[3]='Bill'
/div/p[4]='Link'
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre Novatchev. I tested it and it worked too.