# Get the XPath of every node that contains a specific attribute using XmlReader?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlreader

I have a variable XML that might look something like this:

```
<content>
    <main editable="true">
        <h1>Here is my header</h1>
        <p>Here is my content</p>
    </main>
    <buttons>
        <positive editable="true">I agree!</positive>
        <negative editable="true">No - get me outta here!</negative>
    </button>
</content>
```

I'd like to get the XPath for all of the nodes that have the attribute "editable" that equals "true".  Please note that the attributes can be at variable node levels so I can't just loop through all the nodes at one level and check for the attribute.  I'd also like to use XmlReader because of the speed but if there's a better/faster way, then I'm open to that as well.

```
var xml = IO.File.ReadAllText(contentFilePath);
var readXML = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml));

readXML.ReadToFollowing("content");

while (readXML.Read()) {
    //???
}
```

Comment: If you are reading all the text to a string, I think you lose the main benefit of XmlReader...

Comment: @Jacob Ah well, that's good to know.  What's the fastest way to do it if the file is on the file system?  Read the bytes and provide the stream instead?

Comment: @RichC How large are your files? The performance benefit is arguably not worth it unless they are *very* large.

Comment: `XmlReader` doesn't make the parent stack publicly available so you'd have to create your own pushdown stack as the reader goes into and out of elements.  For an alternative, read into an `XElement` then do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451950/get-the-xpath-to-an-xelement

Comment: Also, are you looking to construct an absolute XPath expression string *from* the element, or are you trying to figure out how to select all nodes with the editable attribute set to true *using* XPath? (sorry if this is just my poor english interpretation)

Comment: I basically have a "master" XML that tells me which nodes are editable.  I need a collection of XPaths from this file.  Then I need open a different XML file (which is provided by the user) to pull out and display the inner contents of each XPath node from that file.  I need the FULL XPath so I can easily query the values in the second XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone's feedback, I went with this code for my solution:

```
Dim xml = IO.File.ReadAllText(masterLangDir)
Dim xdoc = New XmlDocument()
xdoc.LoadXml(xml)
Dim xPaths = findAllNodes(xdoc.SelectSingleNode("content"), New List(Of String))

public List<string> findAllNodes(XmlNode node, List<string> xPaths)
{
    foreach (XmlNode n in node.ChildNodes) {
        var checkForChildNodes = true;
        if (n.Attributes != null) {
            if (n.Attributes("editable") != null) {
                if (n.Attributes("editable").Value == "true") {
                    xPaths.Add(GetXPathToNode(n));
                    checkForChildNodes = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (checkForChildNodes) {
            xPaths = findAllNodes(n, xPaths);
        }
    }
    return xPaths;
}

public string GetXPathToNode(XmlNode node)
{
    if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Attribute) {
        // attributes have an OwnerElement, not a ParentNode; also they have             
        // to be matched by name, not found by position             
        return String.Format("{0}/@{1}", GetXPathToNode(((XmlAttribute)node).OwnerElement), node.Name);
    }
    if (node.ParentNode == null) {
        // the only node with no parent is the root node, which has no path
        return "";
    }

    // Get the Index
    int indexInParent = 1;
    XmlNode siblingNode = node.PreviousSibling;
    // Loop thru all Siblings
    while (siblingNode != null) {
        // Increase the Index if the Sibling has the same Name
        if (siblingNode.Name == node.Name) {
            indexInParent += 1;
        }
        siblingNode = siblingNode.PreviousSibling;
    }

    // the path to a node is the path to its parent, plus "/node()[n]", where n is its position among its siblings.         
    return String.Format("{0}/{1}[{2}]", GetXPathToNode(node.ParentNode), node.Name, indexInParent);
}
```

[I picked up the GetXPathToNode function from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241238/how-to-get-xpath-from-an-xmlnode-instance).